# Flask 405 Error Method Not Allowed on Post Request

Tags: python, flask, post, routes, http-status-code-405

I have been running my flask program for awhile and out of the blue the 405 method not allowed error came up.

Prodsearch.html

```
<form name="product search" action="" method="post" novalidate>
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <legend>Database Search</legend>
                {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
                <p>
                <h6>Search: </h6>
                {{ form.input(size=20) }}
<!--                <input type = "file" name = "file" />-->
                {% for error in form.input.errors %}
                <span class="error-message">{{ error }}</span>
                {% endfor %}
                </p>
                <p>
                    {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-primary") }}
                </p>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
```

routes.py

```
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/Prodsearch', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def prodsearch():
...
    return render_template('Prodsearch.html', form=form, vol_data=data)
```

forms.py

```
class ProdSearch(FlaskForm):
    input = StringField("Enter name search key word", validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField("Search")
```

I don't know why this error suddenly occurred out of nowhere. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the first route to

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
```

Comment: What happens when you open "/Prodsearch" in your browser?

Comment: It opens properly. It only breaks on the submission of the post request.

Comment: Try changing the first route to `@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])`

Comment: Cool,  Can you mark my answer as correct? (I edited the original answer)